# k-linear categories

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory

I have read several times about $k$-linear categories. I understand in general the construction of enriched categories.

But in the special case of vector spaces I am confused about the vector space addition. 
If the Hom spaces are vector spaces, where does the addition come from? Composing isn't commutative, so that doesn't work...

In particular,  I have a semisimple category $\mathcal{C}$ which is a module category over $\mathrm{vect}_k$ - meaning there exist an action on both objects $V.C$ ($V \in \mathrm{vect}$ and $C \in \mathcal{C}$) and morphisms $f.\phi$ with $f$ vector morphism and $\phi \in \mathcal{C}$.

I want to show that this is $k$-linear i.e. that $\mathrm{Hom}(C, C')$ is a vector space $\forall C, C' \in \mathcal{C}$.

I got the scalar multiplication with help of the action on morphisms, but how does one get the addition?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't your semisimple category already additive?

Answer (score 1):

In general, enrichment is extra structure, and you need to specify it. It's worth understanding in detail the one-object case: for $V$ a monoidal category (such as vector spaces with tensor product), a one-object $V$-enriched category is a monoid in $V$. So, for example, a one-object $k$-linear category is a $k$-algebra. It has an underlying category which is given by forgetting the vector space structure and remembering only the multiplication; you need to specify the vector space structure, and in particular the addition, as extra data on top of this.

However, enrichment over commutative monoids has a very peculiar property, which is that under mild hypotheses (the existence of either finite products or finite coproducts) it is actually determined by the bare category structure. See [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/) for a lengthy discussion of how this works.